# JavaScript clone the form without incrementing id for each form fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I tried using clone function in javascript, but the problem is after I clone the form, all the functionalities are lost. 
I also used clone.value("") to clear value in previous form, but it is still not working as I expected. Here is the link to the complete code https://jsfiddle.net/meredithlou/b07berha/

```
 <script>


       app.controller("usercontroller", function($scope){ 
                 $scope.countryList = [  
               "Java", "JavaScript","C++"];
                //break
             $scope.complete = function(string){  
               $scope.hidethis = false;  
               var output = [];
               //push the course number into list  
               angular.forEach($scope.countryList, function(country){  
                    if(country.toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase()) >= 0)  
                    {  
                         output.push(country);  
                    }  
               });  
               //filter function
               $scope.filterCountry = output;  
          }  
          $scope.fillTextbox = function(string){  
               $scope.country = string;  
               $scope.hidethis = true;  
          }  
     });  
        //Shows different menu options when certain category is selected
            function populate(s1,s2){
                var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
                var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
                s2.innerHTML = "";
                 //if else statement when certain category is selected
                if(s1.value == "QR"){
                    var optionArray = ["|","first|first Unit of Instruction","secondPass|Second Pass","lecture|Lecture","others|Others"];
                } else if(s1.value == "VE"){
                    var optionArray = ["|","video|Video import","videoColor|Video Coloring","videoRemake|Video Remake","others|Others"];
                } else if(s1.value == "AO"){
                    var optionArray = ["|","course|Course Charter","budget|Course Budget","others|Others"];
                }
                //parse the array 
                for(var option in optionArray){
                    var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
                    var newOption = document.createElement("option");
                    newOption.value = pair[0];
                    newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
                    s2.options.add(newOption);
                }
            }

          </script> 
     <!--This part is for project name, subtopic, subtask and hours -->

             <div class="selectCategory" id="selct" style="width:900px;" >  

             <form class="form-main" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                 <h4>Choose one of the categories</h4>
                 <input  type="radio" ng-model="myCat" value="Course">Course
                  <input type="radio" ng-model="myCat" value="Project">Administration Overhead

             <div ng-switch="myCat">
               <!-- break -->
               <!-- when course radio button is selected -->
               <div ng-switch-when="Course">
                 <h5>Select the Course Number</h5>
                 <div ng-controller="usercontroller">     
                         <input type="text" name="country" id="country" ng-model="country" ng-keyup="complete(country)" class="form-control" />  
                         <ul class="list-group" ng-model="hidethis" ng-hide="hidethis">  
                              <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="countrydata in filterCountry" ng-click="fillTextbox(countrydata)">{{countrydata}}</li>  
                         </ul>  
                 </div>  
                   <!-- break -->
                   <!-- main categories -->
                   <h6><strong>Select one of the categories</strong></h6>
                   <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="QR">Quality Review</option>
                  <option value="VE">Video Editing</option>
                  <option value="AO">Admin Overhead</option>
                </select>
                   <br/>
                <h6>Select one of the task</h6>
                <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
<!-- break -->
                 <br/>
                 <br/> 
                <!--input for hours-->
                <h7>Please input hours for this task: </h7>
                 <br/>
                <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
                    </div>

                 <!-- break -->
                  <!-- break -->
                 <!-- break -->
                 <!-- break -->
                   <!-- break -->
                   <!-- break -->

                 <!-- same menu option like above without course number -->
                 <!-- when the project is selected -->
                 <div ng-switch-when="Project">
                  <h6><strong>Select one of the categories</strong></h6>
                   <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
                   <!-- list of options -->
                  <option value=""></option>
                  <option value="QR">Quality Review</option>
                  <option value="VE">Video Editing</option>
                  <option value="AO">Admin Overhead</option>
                </select>
                   <br/>
                 <!-- subcategory -->
                <h6>Select one of the task</h6>
                <select id="slct2" name="slct2"></select>
                 <br/>
                 <br/> 
                <h7>Please input hours for this task: </h7>
                 <br/>
                <input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">


                 </div>

                 </div>
                 </form>

              </div>
           <!-- add and remove buttons -->
           <button type="button"  id="btn"  class="btn btn-success add-more-btn">Add More Forms</button>
           <button type="button" id="rmbtn"  class="btn btn-success">Remove this Form</button>
        <!-- end of the form -->
       </body>
```

Comment: The sample code doesn't contain any calls to [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)... should it?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not complete code so it makes it hard to give you a full solution BUT please keep in mind that element IDs are meant to be unique so even if you dynamically created a second form with replicated IDs, your code would still not function as expected as it would only grab the first element with the specified ID that it finds to operate on. You will need to refactor both your html and js to retrieve/operate on elements by means other than id (think classes).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Here is the link to complete code. https://jsfiddle.net/meredithlou/b07berha/ However, when I clone the form, how do I also create new ids?